# UIBarButtonItem font reverts after navigation

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uikit

I am using a subclass of UINavigationController to set the appearance of a UIBarButtonItem.  When the navigation stack first appears, the font is correct (on the button labelled "Item").  However, after navigating to a new screen, the font for the new UIBarButton item ("Test") has reverted to the default appearance.  When I navigate back the original UIBarButton item ("Item") has also reverted to the default appearance.

Is this a bug or am I doing it incorrectly?

Here is my subclass.

```
import UIKit

open class CustomNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    override init(rootViewController: UIViewController) {
        super.init(rootViewController: rootViewController)
        self.style()
    }

    required public init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        self.style()
    }

    override public init(navigationBarClass: AnyClass?, toolbarClass: AnyClass?) {
        super.init(navigationBarClass: navigationBarClass, toolbarClass: toolbarClass)
        self.style()
    }


    override public init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
        self.style()
    }

    func style() {

        let color = UIColor.green
        let font = UIFont.init(name: "Zapfino", size: 18)!

        let attributes: [AnyHashable : Any] = [
            NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : color,
            NSAttributedString.Key.font : font
                       ]
        UIBarButtonItem
            .appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [CustomNavigationController.self])
            .setTitleTextAttributes((attributes as! [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]), for: .normal)

        let highlightedAttributes: [AnyHashable : Any] = [
            NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : color,
            NSAttributedString.Key.font : font
        ]

        UIBarButtonItem
            .appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [CustomNavigationController.self])
            .setTitleTextAttributes((highlightedAttributes as! [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]), for: .highlighted)

    }

}
```

Here is a screenshot of the storyboard.

[image: the storyboard]

Answer (score 0):

While I'm certain this is a bug on the part of Apple, I was able to workaround it by creating a custom UINavigationBar class and intercepting the bar button items.

You then just need to set the class of the UINavigationBar in the storyboard or using `UINavigationController:initWithNavigationBarClass`

```
class CustomNavigationBar: UINavigationBar {

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    func color() -> UIColor { return UIColor.green }
    func font() -> UIFont { return UIFont.init(name: "Zapfino", size: 18)! }

    func attributes() -> [NSAttributedString.Key : Any] {
        return [
            NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : self.color(),
            NSAttributedString.Key.font : self.font()
        ]
    }

    let appearance =  UIBarButtonItem.appearance()

    override var backItem: UINavigationItem? {
        let item = super.backItem
        item?.backBarButtonItem?.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes(), for: .normal)
        item?.rightBarButtonItem?.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes(), for: .normal)

        return item
    }

    override var topItem: UINavigationItem? {
        let item = super.topItem
         item?.backBarButtonItem?.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes(), for: .normal)
        item?.rightBarButtonItem?.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes(), for: .normal)
        return item
    }

    override func setItems(_ items: [UINavigationItem]?, animated: Bool) {

        super.setItems(items, animated: animated)

        guard let items = items else { return }

        for item in items  {
            item.backBarButtonItem?.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes(), for: .normal)
        }

    }

}
```